# Wordpress: How to redirect a post to an another post?

Tags: php, wordpress, redirect

I have searched a lot, and only thing i found is `wp_redirect()`.  To use that function, I need to edit the files in the site. But i want to use only one file to communicate with my wordpress site. So, is there any other way to redirect a post from an additional php file like this:

```
redirect_post_to_link($post_id, $link);
```

I have tried (the first method that comes to mind) updating the post content to `<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0;URL=https://www.examplewpsite.com/postblabla">` with

```
include("wp-load.php")
$post = get_post( $post_id );
$post->post_content = $redirect_code
$update_output = wp_update_post( $post );
if($update_output != 0){ // ...code continues...
```

but it doesn't actually update the post, when you visit the post you get blank content.

sorry if i asked a incorrect question.

Comment: Although I’m generally against “just throw a plugin it”, and prefer code, for this I’d recommend installing [Redirection](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/). Inevitably you will have additional redirects over time, and this plugin does a great job of managing it. It also tracks 404s which is very helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just found how to solve this. removing filter during update progress by `kses_remove_filters()` makes me able to update the content whatever i want.